# Image editor which can handle layer groups

Tags: software-recommendation, image-editing

What free image editors exist for the Mac, which can handle *.psd files and treats layer groups correctly (for example, GIMP just ignores layer grouping)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two "great" image programs for the Mac at this time, so if Gimp doesn't do it your only valid alternatives are [Pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com/) and [Acorn](http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/).

I have an old version of Pixelmator that doesn't do Layer Groups (1.x), from what I can see, 2.x doesn't do it either. I have Acorn and although it mentions PSD compatibility (and Layers) I don't have a .PSD file (because I don't have Adobe Photoshop).

So you can download a trial version (of Acorn at least) and give it a try.

Comment: with all due respect - it is kinda strange answer: "I don't know, but I definitely know that there are two great programs, first definitely doesn't do it, second - well, try yourself.

Comment: But - but! - nevertheless it turns out that Acorn supports grouping, so upvoting.

Comment: @shabunc I'm sorry you didn't find my answer pleasing. As I've said, I don't have a PSD file to test the feature and although the Acorn website does mention Layers and Groups, it doesn't explicitly say that it supports importing them from Photoshop. I gave you the names and the links, only you can decide if what the software does is what you need.